# Adding Aria labels to the video element

Tags: html, video, wai-aria

Here's my code:

```html
<video id="video" width="320" height="240"   preload="none"  poster="cat.jpg" controls >
    <source  src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source  src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <a href="catvideo.ogg">Download the video </a>
</video>
```

I tried validating my code with Firefox accessibility inspector and this bit of code had five errors.
I tried adding  `aria-labelledby , aria-label, <label>, alt="some-text"`, but nothing seems to work .
I'm unsure what else to do.

Thanks

Comment: "this bit of code had five errors" — What errors?

Comment: I mean labeled as missing the correct aria text labels ? It seems to be missing 2 progressbar text labels and 2 slider text labels and a graphic label ?